# Reiterate Teradata SQL with date variables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I have a SQL script that pulls data only within the previous date. The query is currently run on every date and inserts the results into a table.

Now I want to make some small changes to the calculation logic and then reiterate this query so that I can have the new data for the last year using the new logic. My question is how I can reiterate this SQL script and automate it. It's basically replacing current_date with each historical date in the past year and re-run it 365 times.

A simplified structure of the current query is the below:

```
With CTEa as ( select a, b, c from Xtable where dt = current_date - 1)
, CTEb as (select d, e from CTEa join Ytable on .... where current_date between adate and bdate)
, insert into Ztable (select g, f from CTEb)
```

I've been trying to use the stored procedure but have not successful.

Comment: If your question is about stored procedure coding, edit the question to show what you are trying and where you are having difficulty. But as a rule, it's more efficient to use SQL to process the date range in parallel rather than iteratively.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions (CTE) for Teradata syntax appears to require the WITH expression to immediately precede the SELECT, like so:

```
insert into Ztable
With 
   CTEa as (select a, b, c from ...),
   CTEb as (select a, b, c from CTEa)
from CTEb
```

I am not sure if I understand what you mean by *re-run it 365 times* but why wouldn't something like this (why are you using CTE?):

```
insert into Ztable
select a, b  
from Xtable 
where dt between current_date-366 and current_date - 1
```